# Temporary lifetime variable MSVC different behaviour from GCC

Tags: c++

I'm wondering if anyone can explain the difference in behaviour between GCC/Clang and MSVC for this code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
public:
    Base(int* a) : ptr{a} { std::cout << "Base construct\n"; }
    ~Base() { std::cout << "Base destruct\n"; }

    int* ptr;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    Derived() : Base(&val) { std::cout << "Derived construct\n"; }

    ~Derived() { std::cout << "Derived destruct\n"; }
protected:
    int val{2};
};

Derived GiveMeDerived() {
    return {};
}

void SomeFunc(Base b) {
    std::cout << "SomeFunc " << *b.ptr << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    SomeFunc(GiveMeDerived());

    return 0;
}
```

In GCC/Clang, I see the expected printout order of:

```
Base construct
Derived construct
SomeFunc 2
Base destruct
Derived destruct
Base destruct
```

but in MSVC 2022 (MSVC 19.39.33523.0), I get:

```
Base construct
Derived construct
SomeFunc 2
Base destruct
Base destruct
Derived destruct
Base destruct
```

Where does the extra base destruct come from?

When I change to code to try to track creation:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
public:
    // Base() { std::cout << "Default\n"; }

    Base(int* a) : ptr{a} { std::cout << "Base construct\n"; }
    ~Base() { std::cout << "Base destruct " << default_des << "\n"; }

    int* ptr;
    std::string default_des{"default"};
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    Derived() : Base(&val) { std::cout << "Derived construct\n"; }

    ~Derived() { std::cout << "Derived destruct\n"; }
protected:
    int val{2};
};

Derived GiveMeDerived() {
    Derived a;
    a.default_des = "From GiveMeDerived\n";
    return a;
}

void SomeFunc(Base b) {
    std::cout << "SomeFunc " << *b.ptr << "\n";
    b.default_des = "inside SomeFunc";
}

int main()
{
    SomeFunc(GiveMeDerived());

    return 0;
}
```

MSVC seems to "fix" itself and does not have the extra destructor:

```
Base construct
Derived construct
SomeFunc 2
Base destruct inside SomeFunc
Derived destruct
Base destruct From GiveMeDerived
```

Comment: You have *undefined behavior*. That means anything could happen. The two main problems is the *object slicing* and *copying* that happens for the call to `SomeFunc`.

Comment: Your code does [object slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing). If you dont know what it is, read about it. If you do it on purpose, reconsider whether its a good idea.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Why do you think the behavior is undefined? Slicing itself is not UB.

Comment: This example was made to try to help understand the lifetimes of some of the objects passed around in one of nvidia's SDK/libraries (which does these weird object slicing). One of the main points I was trying to understand was when the temporary Derived object passed into SomeFunc actually destructs.

Comment: Temporaries live until the end of the full expression they are in.  In this case the temporary `Derived` lives until the `;` of `SomeFunc(GiveMeDerived());`.

Comment: the non-virtual destructor can be an issue, but not sure if it is relevant here

Comment: The extra dtor in MSVC may be related to which C++ standard you are using. MSVC 2022 defaults to c++14, but you can also use C++17 or C++20.

Comment: @Eugene I just tried with 14, 17, and 20, and they all have the same behaviour.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai just the opposite: a virtual dtor would make the slicing undefined behavior.

Comment: That is interesting I can reproduce this https://godbolt.org/z/PvrYfxjqf , but when I add explicit copy constructor MSVC behaves same as gcc. I suspect that RVO is used or not.

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/wrong-codegen-copy-constructor-not-elided-when-the/1147235 (Possibly related to https://wg21.link/class.temporary#3 where the "destructor of `X` is either trivial or deleted" check is skipped)

Comment: @MarekR That could be related to compiling for Debug or Release. I think I've seen MSVC skipping RVO in debug builds

Comment: @PepijnKramer I've compiled this with only difference `/D HAS_EXPLICIT_COPY` so debug/release has nothing to that.

Comment: @MarekR Check :)

Comment: btw, using a static check, the slicing is detected: https://godbolt.org/z/57fTxPq9z

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in the Microsoft x86 calling convention.

If you cross compile with clang to Windows, you see the same behaviour in clang (which clang states is [non-conforming](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/fcbe17c6be86c87031822c1c01d8b43b6d142695/clang/lib/Sema/SemaDeclCXX.cpp#L5905-L5914) but implements to act the same as MSVC).

[[class.temporary]p3](https://wg21.link/class.temporary#3) in the standard allows compilers to introduce temporaries for function arguments. However, this is only for types that are trivially destructible.

The Microsoft ABI skips that check and passes `Base` in a register anyways, requiring a copy. It is as-if you wrote:

```cpp
{
    Derived required_temporary = GiveMeDerived();
    Base invented_temporary = std::move(required_temporary);
    SomeFunc(std::move(invented_temporary));
}
```

Where `required_temporary` is the temporary that's materialized from the return value of `GiveMeDerived()`, but `invented_temporary` is non-conforming.

(If you run this on windows, it will create yet another non-conforming temporary for the argument of `SomeFunc`)

---

This is also the reason that this disappears when you add a `std::string` member: the class is no longer trivially copyable, so the calling convention doesn't call for it to be passed in a register. It also becomes too big.